# Applying migration script not working, no files to deploy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, entity-framework-core, yaml

I'm generating a migration and then applying it to a database but I'm getting a weird error about not having any files to deploy.

```
No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\1\s
```

Here is the YAML definition for my pipeline

```
variables:
 solution: '**/*.sln'
 buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
 buildConfiguration: 'Release'
 dbProject: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\PointOfSaleApp.DB\PointOfSaleApp.DB.csproj'
 startUpProject: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\PointOfSaleApp\PointOfSaleApp.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create migration'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: ef
    arguments: 'migrations script -i -o $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\migration.sql --project $(dbProject) -s $(startUpProject)'

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Apply database migrations
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MySub'
    ServerName: '$(sqlserver).database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: $(sqldb)
    SqlUsername: $(sqluser)
    SqlPassword: "hardcoded_password_because_passing_it_another_way_just_doesnt_work"
    SqlFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\migration.sql'
```

The pipeline is executed in the cloud, not running on my machine.

I have tried setting the pipeline variable `system.debug` to `true` and I'm not getting more information.

At least, nothing very revealing

```
##[debug]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\1\sCheck out 
how to troubleshoot failures at 
https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
##[debug]At D:\a\_tasks\SqlAzureDacpacDeployment_ce85a08b-a538-4d2b-8589- 
1d37a9ab970f\1.178.1\DeploySqlAzure.ps1:220 char:5
```

Do I need to copy the SQL file somewhere ? I'm providing the same path for both tasks so I'm a bit puzzled.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing the debug logs, I saw this:

```
##[debug]INPUT_BACPACFILE: 'D:\a\1\s'
##[debug]INPUT_DACPACFILE: 'D:\a\1\s'
```

Which led me to believe the task was looking for a BACPAC or DACPAC file instead of my .sql file.

I found that when executing an SQL file, an extra option needs to be specified in the task's YAML.

```
deployType: "sqlTask"
```